# My Heroku app seems to be running more than 1 instance

Tags: python, heroku, groupme

As the title says, I have an app hosted on Heroku that seems to have more than one instance running.  This is a problem because I am trying to keep track of single letter posts on a GroupMe in order to see if they spell anything.  I am using python and a global string variable that I can add the characters to.  Since there is more than one instance, there is more than 1 global variable so sometimes the character gets added to one or the other which defeats the purpose of the program.  Has anyone else run into this problem or found a fix to this?  Thanks.

Comment: I have a similar thing with a rails / react app that has both a https version and an http version and the http version doesn't update to my current code base but is still there. Hope you get an answer!

Answer (score 1):

So after thinking about possible ways to fix it, I decided to try to keep my global variables inside a json file and then edit that each time.  This worked as I believe that even if there were 2 version of the actual code running, they should both edit the same json file.